# Providing the correct match for a list in a list of lists in R

Tags: r

I have  a list of lists in R:

```
a <- list(x=0, y=c(1,2,3), z=4)
b <- list(x=1, y=c(1,2,3), z=44)
c <- list(x=2, y=c(1,2,3), z=444)
L <- list(a,b,c)
```

For a given list, say

```
l <- list(x=0, y=c(1,2,3), z=4)
```

I know want to find the correct index of `L` where we find the corresponding list that equals `l`.

Of course, I can use a loop, but since `L`is very large, I need a faster solution.
(And is a list even the right choice here?)

Comment: You meant `l <- list(x=0, y=c(1,2,3), z=4)`, didn't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `stack` with `identical` from `base R`

```
which(sapply(L, function(x) identical(stack(l), stack(x))))
#[1] 1
```

---

Or more compactly

```
which(sapply(L, identical, l))
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mapply` to compare each element one by one with `l`. If you `unlist` it, `all` should be `TRUE`. Using `which` around an `sapply` finally gives the number of the matching element.

```
f <- function(x) all(unlist(mapply(`==`, x, l)))

which(sapply(L, f))
# [1] 1
```

---

*Data:*

```
L <- list(list(x = 0, y = c(1, 2, 3), z = 4), list(x = 1, y = c(1, 
2, 3), z = 44), list(x = 2, y = c(1, 2, 3), z = 444))

l <- list(x = 0, y = c(1, 2, 3), z = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `mapply` like below

```
> which(mapply(identical, L, list(l)))
[1] 1
```